# StreamWrite xml Node content ignoring children using C#

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I am trying to wrtie a program that reads a rss news feed and rewrites the date, the title and the body of the article on a txt file. I've only just learnt C# two days ago, but have experience with other languages.
The program works fine for some feeds, however in others (for example Reuters) there is a "email this article" type link after each article body and I can't seem to get rid of it when copying it. I run the program for the entire feed.

For example, this is the xml code for some news:

```
<item>
  <title>Pimco's Ivascyn sees 'significant' opportunity in European bank assets</title>
  <link>http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/news/wealth/~3/vUJ74S5mXQg/story01.htm</link>
  <category domain="">PersonalFinance</category>
  <pubDate>Mon, 16 Jun 2014 15:37:52 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/06/16/us-investing-pimco-ivascyn-idUSKBN0ER1VV20140616?feedType=RSS&amp;feedName=PersonalFinance</guid>
  <description>NEW YORK (Reuters) - The expected unloading of roughly $1 trillion in assets by European banks represents a "significant investment opportunity" in residential and commercial real estate as well as...&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
  &lt;a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/news/wealth?a=vUJ74S5mXQg:y6BPXasLV5o:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/news/wealth?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/news/wealth/~4/vUJ74S5mXQg" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description
  <feedburner:origLink>http://reuters.us.feedsportal.com/c/35217/f/654211/s/3b8e7c6b/sc/2/l/0L0Sreuters0N0Carticle0C20A140C0A60C160Cus0Einvesting0Epimco0Eivascyn0EidUSKBN0AER1VV20A140A6160DfeedType0FRSS0GfeedName0FPersonalFinance/story01.htm</feedburner:origLink>
</item>
```

However when I run the program I get:

```
Mon, 16 Jun 2014 15:37:52 GMT
Pimco's Ivascyn sees 'significant' opportunity in European bank assets
NEW YORK (Reuters) - The expected unloading of roughly $1 trillion in assets by European banks represents a "significant investment opportunity" in residential and commercial real estate as well as...<div class="feedflare">
<a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/news/wealth a=vUJ74S5mXQg:y6BPXasLV5o:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/news/wealth?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a>
</div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/news/wealth/~4/vUJ74S5mXQg" height="1" width="1"/>
**********
```

I am trying to get rid of the last two lines of code after the main text of the article. The asterisks are added by me to separate the different articles.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlReading
{
    class RssReading
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creater a StreamWriter object to write in a text file.
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\Testing002.txt");

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            // Loads the rss feed page
            xmlDoc.Load("http://feeds.reuters.com/news/wealth");

            //create an object of item nodes.
            XmlNodeList itemNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//rss/channel/item");

            foreach (XmlNode itemNode in itemNodes)
            {
                //Reading the title
                XmlNode titleNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
                //Reading the date
                XmlNode dateNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("pubDate");
                //Reading the body 
                XmlNode bodyNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("description");

                if(((titleNode != null) && (dateNode != null)) && (bodyNode!= null))
                {
                  /*    Xpath of article body, and of extra links.
                   *    //*[@id="bodyblock"]/ul/li[2]/div/text()
                   *    //*[@id="bodyblock"]/ul/li[2]/div/div
                   */
                //writing to console just to check the output.
                    Console.WriteLine(dateNode.InnerText);
                    sw.WriteLine(dateNode.InnerText);

                    Console.WriteLine(titleNode.InnerText);
                    sw.WriteLine(titleNode.InnerText);

                    Console.WriteLine(bodyNode.Value);
                    sw.WriteLine(bodyNode.InnerText);

                    Console.WriteLine("**********\n\n\n");
                    sw.WriteLine("**********\n\n\n");
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");
                    sw.WriteLine(" ");

                }
            }
            sw.Close();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Your 'XML-code' is not an XML-structure for an RSS-feed. It is an HTML-representation of it. Please provide the XML-structure that you're trying to process.

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the issue. Initially I thought it was a problem of children, however I realised that the "email this" link was created using entities (such as:

```
&lt;
```

and

```
&gt;
```

Hence all I did was to use substring stating from position 0 until index of first '&' character. Also in order to make the code run even when rss readers don't have this problem I wrote it using Math.Max to avoid negative size of substrings.

Final code remains the same a part from the line in which the body is written in to text file. There the code is replaced with the following line:

```
sw.WriteLine(bodyNode.InnerText.Substring(0,Math.Max(bodyNode.InnerXml.IndexOf("&"),0)));
```

Also now the Console.WriteLine() are not needed in the code.

Comment: This method will not work when you have character entities (like &gt;, &amp; etc.) in the text that you would like to keep. You could HTML-decode the description text and after that use a regular expression to remove the HTML tags. A less sophisticated solution but slightly better than the one you have now is not to search for '&', but for '&lt;', because this would be a more accurate search for the start of an HTML tag.

Comment: Which is what I tried initially. However for some reason it would write only the body of one of the articles correctly, and write nothing for any of the other articles.